# Limit of sequence of sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I got to thinking about sequences of Cauchy sequences. Here is a simple example. Let us define $b_n = (n,1,1,1,...)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. So we have
\begin{align}
b_1&=(1,1,1,1,...)\\
b_2&=(2,1,1,1,...)\\
b_3&=(3,1,1,1,...)\\
\dots
\end{align}
Question: what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$? It looks like that is not a valid sequence. Does this question even make sense? (I am not sure how such a limit would even be defined.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence in $X$ is actually a function $\mathbb N\to X$ or equivalently an element of the set $X^\mathbb N$.

If $X$ is a topological space then $X^{\mathbb N}$ can be equipped with a topology that corresponds in some way with the original topology on $X$, which gives birth to the possibility of convergence of sequences.

There are several candidates for the topology on $X^{\mathbb N}$.

In each of them a sequence of sequences might have a limit.

The question whether $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ exists (so that the expression makes sense) depends heavily on this context.

Comment: Thank you! So what about $X=\mathbb Q$, which I suppose is the simplest case? (I am thinking about the context of a construction of the real numbers.) Is there a natural topology and if so what can we say about the limit of $b_n$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ with its usual topology is a metric space. Then a candidate is uniform topology based on metric $\rho((a_n)_n,(b_n)_n)=\inf\{\overline d(a_n,b_n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ where $\overline d(a_n,b_n$ stands for $\min\{|a_n-b_n|,1)$. Always there is the topology of pointwise convergence where sequence $(a_n)_n$ convergences iff $a_n$ converges for every $n$. And there are more (topology of compact convergence, compact-open topology, test-open topology, product topology). I cannot find one that makes your sequence $(b_n)_n$ converge.

Comment: In your comment  to your A, I think you meant  $\sup$, not $\inf,$ in the def'n of $\rho$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, you are right. Thank you for attending me.